# Powershell command to trim path if it ends with "\"

Tags: powershell, filepath, text-parsing, ends-with

I need to trim path if it ends with `\`.

```
C:\Ravi\
```

I need to change to

```
C:\Ravi
```

I have a case where path will not end with `\` (Then it must skip).

I tried with `.EndsWith("\")`, but it fails when I have `\\` instead of `\`.

Can this be done in PowerShell without resorting to conditionals?

Comment: Why do you need to trim this path? Depending on your requirement, there may be a better way to handle it (for example, if you're concatenating strings into a path, `Join-Path` will handle it for you without trimming).

Comment: @alroc I am not building path. I am extracting and then defining as required.

Comment: `Split-Path` may prove useful to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

no need to overcomplicate

```
"C:\Ravi\".trim('\')
```

Comment: That works, but because it trims from _both_ ends, it doesn't work for UNC-based paths such as `\\foo\bar`.

Comment: "\\server\Ravi\".trimend('\') will fix it for UNC paths.

Answer (score 58):

Consider using `TrimEnd` instead (especially if you are working with `UNC` Path):

```
"C:\Ravi\".TrimEnd('\')
```

Answer (score 3):

You mention needing to differentiate between paths ending in "\" and "\\" and possibly handling those differently. While you can use `.Trim("\")` or `.TrimEnd("\")` to remove the trailing "\" character in the example you gave, both those methods will strip *all* trailing slashes from your path.

The following regex will return **True** if your path ends in a single "\" but false if it ends in multiple "\" characters:

```
$Path -match '.+[^\\]\\$'
```

The regex means:

1. A string of as many characters as possible,
2. Up to something that is NOT a backslash
3. Followed by one backslash

Giving:

```
"C:\Ravi\" -match '.+[^\\]\\$'
True

"C:\Ravi\\" -match '.+[^\\]\\$'
False
```

Hope this helps / is interesting. :-)

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Note: This solution is only of interest if you need to trim *at most* 2 trailing `\` chars., want to support `/` path separators too, want to handle root paths correctly or are generally interested in regex techniques.

**If it's acceptable to trim *any* nonempty run of trailing `\` chars., i.e., also *3 or more* (which is quite likely in this case) and *root* paths need no special treatment, use [Martin Brandl's simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37114970/45375).**</sup>

A solution based on PowerShell's [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) with a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) that handles both trailing `\` and `\\` and also works with `/`, given that PowerShell accepts both `\` and `/` as the path separator (which will also make the solution work with PowerShell *Core*, the cross-platfom edition):<sup>[1]</sup>

```
# Remove at most 2 trailing "\" chars.
PS> 'C:\Ravi\' -replace '[\\/]?[\\/]$'
C:\Ravi

#'# More simply, remove any number of trailing "\" chars.
PS> 'C:\Ravi\' -replace '[\\/]+$'  #'# equivalent of 'C:\Ravi\'.TrimEnd('\/')
C:\Ravi
```

- `[\\/]` is a character class (`[...]`) that matches a single character that is either `\` (escaped as `\\` to be treated as a literal) or `/`.
- `[\\/]?[\\/]` matches *one or two* `\` instances at the end (`$`) of the string, `[\\/]+` more loosely matches *one or more* (`+`).
- Not specifying a *replacement string* effectively *removes* the match from the string; if there is no match, the input string is left as-is.

To demonstrate that the approach works with a variety of paths, including UNC paths:

```
'C:\Ravi', 'C:\Ravi\', 'C:/Ravi/', 'C:\Ravi\\', '\\foo\bar\',  'C:\', '\' | % { 
  $_ -replace '[\\/]?[\\/]$'
}
```

The above yields:

```
C:\Ravi
C:\Ravi
C:/Ravi
C:\Ravi
\\foo\bar
C:
```

Note, however, that **handling of root paths is problematic**: `C:\` was transformed to `C:`, and `\` resulted in the *empty* string.

Fixing that - by leaving a trailing `\` in these special cases - requires a significantly more complex regex (slightly simplified by matching any number of trailing path separators):

```
'C:\Ravi', 'C:\Ravi\', 'C:\', 'C:\\', '\', '\\' | % { 
  $_ -replace '(?:^((?:[a-z]:)?\\)\\*$)|(.*?)(?:\\+)$', '$1$2'
}
```

This yields:

```
C:\Ravi
C:\Ravi
C:\
C:\
\
\
```

Note how the root paths now end in (one) `\`.

The special-casing of root paths is cumbersome, which is why it is **sometimes preferable to *ensure* rather than remove a trailing `\` or `/`** (e.g., `C:\Ravi` -> `C:\Ravi\`), so as to facilitate building paths with simple string concatenation (without having to worry about doubling `\` chars.); the regex becomes simple again:

```
'C:\Ravi', 'C:\Ravi\', 'C:\', 'C:\\', '\', '\\' | % { 
  ($_ -replace '[\\/]+$') + '\'
}
```

This yields:

```
C:\Ravi\
C:\Ravi\
C:\
C:\
\
\
```

Note how *all* paths now end in (one) `\`.

---

<sup>[1] Sometimes string manipulation is necessary, but **oftentimes you can rely on the [`Join-Path` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) to build paths for you, which handles a trailing `\` in the directory part gracefully** (e.g., `Join-Path C:\Ravi\ file.txt` yields `C:\Ravi\file.txt`); by contrast, a trailing `\\` is preserved: `Join-Path C:\Ravi\\ file.txt` yields `C:\Ravi\\file.txt`; however, while that isn't pretty, it is generally benign (such paths still work for accessing the filesystem).</sup>